# Windows Server 2016 IIS force http only for asset resources

Tags: iis, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to force all views in my ASP .NET Core 3.1 MVC project to use http only as I only bound http on my local testing server. However, my views only try to load resources from the https link, and that does not work. When I debug locally from my local development PC, it is also set as http only and that worked. Does anyone have any idea why it does not use the http links while on Windows Server 2016 side?

Comment: Did you get any error messages when using https?

Comment: Nope, no errors using https. The only reason I'm not using https is because it's a testing environment in another domain so I can't get a trusted certificate working on it.

Comment: Is there an error message in the Event Viewer? Without an error message, it is difficult to know your problem.

Comment: Ok I got it, it seems that Chrome is forcing my http site to use https. If I try it using internet explorer it will just work and my assets get loaded from the http link.